# Finding the subgroup in isogeny-based cryptography

Tags: public-key, elliptic-curves, reference-request, post-quantum-cryptography, isogeny

Isogeny-based cryptography is one of the newest post-quantum cryptography. Hardness of this system is based on finding isogeny between two elliptic curves. Also this is theorem:

> Elliptic curves are isogenous over $F_p$ if and only if they have equal
>   number of points.

Recently, isogeny based public key methods are widely used in articles.  This methods are implemented in computer systems in milliseconds and in android systems in seconds. This show that in future we can use such post-quantum cryptographic systems in practical world.

I studied many articles about this method, and I saw only mathematical methods, not practical methods or source code. In program such as the MAGMA we can find all isogenous curves with given curves defined over rational field, but I looking for finite field. Also in sage we can find $l$-isogeny with subgroup of order $l$, but in several time our defined curve have not any subgroup with order $l$.

[This](http://eprint.iacr.org/2006/145.pdf) is one of interesting article. In this article we have some computational example (page $15$). Can you help me fo understand this example. When I send mail to its authors I face with mail error.

How can we find cyclic subgroup of order $l$ of the elliptic curve $E(\overline{\mathbf F_p})$, over the algebraic closure of the finite field?

Comment: On your remark about sage: an $\ell$-isogeny is an isogeny whose kernel is a cyclic subgroup of order $\ell$ of the elliptic curve $E(\overline{\mathbf F_p})$, over the *algebraic closure* of the finite field. Therefore there are $\ell$-isogenies even for $\ell$'s that do not divide the order of $E(\mathbf F_p)$, the group of points defined over the finite field.

Comment: If request for reference recommendations are off-topic, why reference request tag is exist?

Comment: @MeysamGhahramani See [this](http://meta.crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/322/what-should-be-done-with-reference-request-tag) meta question on the tag. Specifically [DW's answer](http://meta.crypto.stackexchange.com/a/324/706). I think your edit is good, so I reopened.

Comment: "This show that in future we can use such post-quantum cryptographic systems in practical world"; actually, this does not address the most fundamental question: is this system secure (against either conventional computers or quantum ones).  IMHO, this system has not been vetted well enough for us to give a confident affirmative to this question.

Comment: @poncho, Until now this system (based on isogeny star) is secure than lattice based systems and its key size is much smaller than lattice base. only problem is slow time for its implementation.

Comment: @MeysamGhahramani: could you then point out the papers analyzing the security of EC Isogeny?  That's not a criticism; I haven't seen anything, and (as you said) that system would be its advantages, should we have confidence in its security.

Comment: @poncho,with quick search in google you can find valuable information about isogeny based cryptography. in page $2$ from "Cryptographic Schemes Based on Isogenies" you can see comparison of hard problems used in cryptography. But this Phd thesis is old($2012$) and now with changing the curves this method became more secure and faster. Also for implementation detail of key exchange you can see "Efficient Implementations of A Quantum-Resistant Key-Exchange Protocol on Embedded systems". Thanks for your attention.

Comment: @poncho Childs, Jao, Soukharev "Constructing elliptic curve isogenies in quantum subexponential time" http://arxiv.org/abs/1012.4019/

Comment: @VadymFedyukovych: that paper specifically does not address supersingular elliptic curves, which is what we use.  If someone finds a similar result that addresses the supersingular case, that would be significant (and we could then remove SIDH from our list of postquantum candidates)

Comment: @poncho Biasse, Jao, Sankar "A quantum algorithm for computing isogenies between supersingular elliptic curves" http://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/techreports/2014/cacr2014-24.pdf and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7YTbf1KkvJs  (at 31:35)

Answer (score 3):

While there is a sub-exponential attack to compute isogenies on ORDINARY elliptic curves (the basis for the Rostovev and Stulbunov paper that you reference) there is not (yet at least) a sub-exponential attack to compute isogenies on SUPERSINGULAR elliptic curves.  The cryptosystem proposed by DeFeo, Jao, and Plut back in 2011 is based on Supersingular rather than ordinary elliptic curves.  Microsoft Research recently published a paper on this cryptosystem.  The paper contains a good overview of research on this problem to date. An preprint of Microsoft's paper is found [here](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/413.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

There is a quantum sub-exponential time algorithm to extract the private keys from the system you cite.  Another [paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2011/506) by Luca De Feo, David Jao, and Jerome Plut improves upon that system, addresses the attack, and gives references to all this, so read that one.

All these post-quantum systems should be considered suspect because recent work has even produced quantum attacks against some symmetric crypto systems! There is good discussion and references [here](http://www.scottaaronson.com/blog/?p=2673) but the important take away is : Although these attacks on symmetric systems assume an unrealistic adversary, that adversary is not unrealistic for a public key system, so periodicity in the system could render it vulnerable to new quantum algorithms.  I think this applies both to isogeny based systems as well as Ring-LWE based systems.

At the same time, all these post-quantum systems remain interesting because they admit slightly different homomorphic properties, meaning they might be useful in different situations.